# Why would I bother properly terminating all threads in a multi-thread process?

Tags: c#, multithreading, visual-studio

The company I work for uses Visual Studio to develop its website and all of its features, and there is also a separate site that's been developed for testing the site. This 'testing' site can run individual test cases against the website, and must be run for each possible case.

Everything is written in VB.NET and each time the program is run a single thread is created to run the test. However, at the 'end' of the test the thread seems to still lingers. The stop button in Visual Studio must be manually clicked in order to terminate the application. Also, a process icon lingers in the task bar long after the application has closed.

It appears to me that the program is not correctly terminating all threads run during the tests, but I'm not sure if this is an issue worth brining up in the office, so I ask the following question...

What is the purpose of properly closing an application and all threads running on it, and what are the consequences, if any, of not doing so?

Comment: Is there any test case that creates threads or calls an async method without any awaiting?

Comment: There are no tests that call any async methods. Every method that pertains to the tests are custom and pertain only to manipulating elements on the web site.

Comment: @thumbmunkeys VB.NET, sorry typo :P

Comment: @Delfino tought so :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it's probably a small problem now, but it's not a good practice, IMHO. Imagine what would happen if the same code was now being executed by a continuous integration server, for instance, TeamCity (or Jenkins, or...), and the unit tests are being run continuously and automatically, by said build server.

What would happen to the build status when those threads fail to close down cleanly? We often face this problem due to bad design decisions in threading, or due to simple (and possibly, idiotic) mistakes in our unit testing code. The net effect though, is a hung build process.

I've seen CI servers hang for almost half a day before someone (mercifully) killed the build process. Essentially, this indicates a problem in our code that may or may not become a huge issue. If this was server-side code, there is potential for this code to lead to a pretty bad situation. My advice would be to dig out your introspection toolkits (memory profiling, perf profiling, etc) and see what exactly is going on, and resolve it.

Comment: I've been trying to monitor each thread that's running during the test, and it seems that even though the test concludes, there are 10-13 threads that are still running in the background.

Comment: I'd recommend using the `CancellationTokenSource` pattern to help you to monitor and kill those threads in an orderly manner.

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar problem with an application that is being called to index SPA pages on our application server. It was throwing an exception in some cases and threads were not closing. The biggest downside is that it will consume the servers memory which is bad
Another downside as it runs as a web application that it will consume available ports and stop running when it run out of available ports.
The code should be modified to peacefully kill the thread after finishing or on exceptions and of course report any.